# How to create Regular expression to Omit Unicode character 'θ'?

Tags: regex, utf-8, xregexp

I have created a regular expression to support UTF8 characters :

```
XRegExp("^(\\p{L}|[0-9_/-]|\\s)+$");
```

Now, i don't want to support unicode character : 'θ'  (theta).

Comment: I'm not the best with regex, but as a fall-back to not figuring it out, you could explicitly check for theta, and if it's not that then use the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead for that:

```
^(?!.*θ)[\p{L}\s0-9_/-]+$
```

In your code:

```
XRegExp("^(?!.*θ)[\\p{L}\\s0-9_/-]+$");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the tiniest tweak to your expression:

```
^(?:(?!θ)\\p{L}|[0-9_/-]+|\\s+)+$
```

The negative lookahead `(?!θ)` ensures that the `\p{L}` you may match is not a `θ`. Also added a `+` quantifier to the `\s` and the middle section so that if we have several in a row we can match them directly without looping through the alternation.

Comment: I still didn't understand why you added + quantifier to \s

Comment: If you have several spaces in a row, `\s+` can match them all in one go. Without the `+`, they are still matched, but the engine matches one... then exits the `()` block... Then starts again in the `()` block, first evaluating `\p{L}` etc. It's slower. Does the regex work for you?

Comment: Well i will test this and let u know.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer this question. If it is not possible then i request admin to close this ticket.

Comment: what should i do with the answers given. Because they are not solving the problem. Is there anyone who can give the response, my profile will get blocked when i don't accept the answer.

Comment: @vermaraj Questions here are not "tickets"; they are useful information other people can find. And we don't close questions based on whether or not they have answers. Finally, not accepting an answer has absolutely nothing to do with a question block.